# Algolia synonym search adding characters

Tags: search, algolia, synonym

Hi I have a problem on this page
https://www.hwl.dk/da/frontpage?q=sp%C3%A6kbr%C3%A6t&hPP=6 
Where the italic text in the search result says things like spækbrætt8 and spækbrættn when I have a two way synonym set up for [spækbræt,skærebræt] and the original text in the search result is "skærebræt".

My question is this:
Why does algolia add t8 and tn and so on to the end of the result when using synonyms.

PS.
The æøå, ÆØÅ letters are native to Denmark by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug in Algolia's API](https://discourse.algolia.com/t/algolia-synonym-search-adding-characters/3441), which is now fixed (as of Friday, November 10th, 2017).